# How to use USB SATA/IDE ADapter

Tags: partitioning, usb, hard-drive, gparted

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.1 LTS.

I want to see and read/write data into an internal HDD from another PC desktop (which also has the same Linux OS).

So I bought an USB SATA/IDE Adapter to connect it into my PC, but...

The File Manager doesn't see it!

GParted tells me: "Can not to create a partition out of the disk!"

But, GParted can see the device!

Gparted shows the unit as an empty device (to be formatted or some), but that unit is almost full of data with 4 partitions plus the swap partition!

So...

How can I use this USB SATA/IDE Adapter?

Which extra software do I need?

Comment: Watch the output of `journalctl --follow` (in a terminal window) as you connect the adapter. Use `mount` to see if it's mounted, `lsblk` to see if it exists.

Comment: Did you connect a power supply to the drive? It can't run off of USB power.

Comment: I used journalctl --follow, nothing is shown. I used lsblk, the unit doesn't exist. I used the power supply which the driver has and the 3 lights of the driver is on. Gparted can see the unit connected to the driver but... It see it as an empty unit! Same thing with Disks. Of course Thunar can not to see the unit. It is the same in my desktop PC and my laptop PC, both with the same Ubuntu Studio OS. This driver works so fine in Windows and MAC. So...

Comment: I tested the USB SATA/IDE driver interface with a brand new HDD which I formatted with just one ext-4 partition (for data) and another Linux swap partition (just in case), and... It is working so fine, now! So... I suspect the driver doesn't work with a HDD which has more than those partitions (some ext-4 and some ntfs, or something else). Maybe it should tested more deeply, but I don't have enough elements and skills to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting worked for me on ubuntu 22.04. When I plugged in the USB cable, `journalctl` shows it start to recognize the drive and then throw a few errors :

```
usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2338, bcdDevice= 1.00
usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
usb 1-3: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge
usb 1-3: Manufacturer: JMicron
...
BPF:Invalid name
...
failed to validate module [usb_storage] BTF: -22
```

Searching those errors led me to this forum, which recommended a reboot: https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/usb-storage-can-not-be-mounted.100480/

I'm unclear of the actual problem, but for me a reboot caused the drive to show up in file manager like any other media.